# Is there any opensource javascript plugin for drawing image maps on images?

Tags: javascript, plugins, imagemap

Found [this one](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/image_map/image_map.php), but it doesn't work for me (Firefox 7.01), any recommendations for js library similar to this one?

What I want to achieve is:

- user should be able to draw some elementar shapes (rectangle,
  circle, elipse) and also polygon drawing mode
- bind added areas to some urls

Thanks

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know that any luck on this? did you got a solution for your problem, as i need the same solution.